# Why are transmission lines and waveguides needed for high frequency?

Tags: rf, circuit-design, microwave, high-frequency

At low frequency, we can just use a piece of wire to connect electrical components, but why are special transmission lines and waveguides needed for high frequency circuits?

Also I am confused by the usages of waveguides in a circuit. In a RF circuit, is it a current that flows through waveguides or is it electromagnetic wave that flow through waveguides? If it's a current, why do we call it a waveguide?

Comment: *is it a current that flows through waveguides or is it electromagnetic wave that flow through waveguides* - these are inseparable things. You can think that the electromagnetic wave is inducing the voltage and current. Or think that the voltage and current are inducing the wave. These are parts of the same phenomenon.

Comment: Essentially because high frequency implies short wavelengths, and things change whether the wavelength is : much larger than the circuit; similar size to the circuit; or much smaller than the circuit. To guide further discussion : Have you studied AC circuits, inductance/capacitance, resonance yet?

Comment: At the instant a light switch is activated, how much current does a wire pass to a 10 metre distant lightbulb? Can the wire exactly know the loading impedance? Can the light switch?

Comment: Transmission Lines are not only a component per se, but also a model to help descrive the behaviour of some components (a couple of wires, a coaxial cable) when their length is not much lower than the operating wavelength. In such a condition, analysing the system with the lumped elements model may lead to mistakes as they are based on  the KVL and KCL laws, that strictly speaking are true only at DC or, in case of non-constant signals, in "small" components.

Comment: Waveguides are useful to carry electromagnetic waves like the water in a tube. Their shield is made by metal so that the wave is reflected inside it as it propagates (you may imagine a tube with mirrors as internal walls). They are not good at low frequencies as, to be able to carry an Electromagnetic Field, their size must be at least half wavelength of the desired operating frequency.

Comment: @Kinka-Byo So, at some point in the RF circuit, is the electromagnetic wave generated and propagated through the waveguide? Or is it that we send the current through the metallic wall of waveguide and as a result the electromagnetic wave is generated?

Comment: @user207787 In a waveguide the wave (excited by a proper source, for instance a small antenna) propagates inside the structure through the multiple reflections in the inner walls of its shield (think the wave as rays and use snell law). You may also image that the EM source induces current on the waveguide metallic shield and such a current generates an EM field, which propagates and generates current on the shield along the structure. The time and space variable current density along the shield is inseparable from the existence of the time and space variable EM feld inside the structure.

Comment: Some waveguides use ground and signal concuctors separated by a dielectric. A signal trace on a PCB can be a waveguide if it is over a ground plane. The wave propagates in the dielectric between signal and ground. Coaxial cable is also a waveguide. The signal propagates in the dielectric between center conductor and shield. At DC, both the trace over ground and the coaxial cable can be regarded as simple wires. Other waveguides are more like metal tubes. The EM wave travels in the void area of the tube.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at it from another angle : A random piece of wire is also a transmission line, and with low frequencies any random tramsmission line will be good enough as low frequencies do not need very good transmission lines, so even one that is very poor transmission line for high frequencies will suffice for low frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. So when we talk about waveguides in RF circuits, do we mean thin metal strips and not hollow metal waveguides? Or do hollow rectangular waveguides used as a part of an electric circuit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> At low frequency, we can just use a piece of wire to connect electrical components, but why are special transmission lines and waveguides needed for high frequency circuits?

Transmission lines are not needed in the sense that it's absolutely impossible without them, but it would be very very difficult to design and debug something that didn't use them, once the dimensions of the circuit are bigger than roughly λ/10 at the operating frequency.

Once you are above that soft limit, any time the impedance of part of the circuit differs from the impedance of the previous part, you get a reflection which significantly affects the operation of the circuit. You still get reflections below that limit, but they don't affect behaviour significantly.

If instead you make everything matched to a common impedance (two frequently used standards are 50 and 75 ohms), reflections at junctions are minimal, and you can simply cascade matched blocks and expect them to work. For instance, it doesn't matter if you use a 1 m or a 2.5 m long 50 ohm cable to your 50 ohm spectrum analyser, it still behaves the same way. If OTOH you had a 75 ohm cable, or worse still a piece of open wire, you would still get some sort of reading, but the amplitude would be dependent on the exact frequency and length of wire, a nightmare to design or debug with, basically impossible to use easily.

> Also I am confused by the usages of waveguides in a circuit. In a RF circuit, is it a current that flows through waveguides or is it electromagnetic wave that flow through waveguides? If it's a current, why do we call it a waveguide?

In an RF circuit, an electromagnetic wave propagates along the waveguide. In coaxial cable, we tend to think of this as a voltage wave across the conductors, and a current wave along the conductors, with a voltage/current ratio equal to the characteristic impedance of the line. In a hollow waveguide, you can consider it as a plane electromagnetic wave zigzagging along the guide, bouncing off the walls, as a result of which a current flows in the walls, and patches of charge appear on the walls.

We call it a waveguide, because the electromagnetic wave is guided by the conductors, as opposed to being a 'free space' wave that propagates out from an antenna.

> When I think of a circuit, I always think a current flowing through the circuit. But in RF, EM wave propagation is always talked about.

When we talk about circuits, and in fact things in general in physics, we try to use the simplest model that captures everything important. In low frequency circuits, just as in high frequency ones, energy is transported by electromagnetic waves (and underneath EM waves there's something going on with photons and relativity that does my head in). However, in low frequency circuits, we can make a simplifying abstraction to just current and voltage, so we do, because it's good enough. In high frequency circuits, it's no longer a good enough approximation, so we have to worry about the waves.

Comment: "In an RF circuit, an electromagnetic wave propagates along the waveguide"

When I think of a circuit, I always think a current flowing through the circuit. But in RF, EM wave propagation is always talked about. Is it because the current moving through the metallic wall of the waveguide induces electromagnetic wave?

Comment: To the OP: The EM wave is captured inside the waveguide. There are localized currents flowing in the walls of the waveguide. You would be hard pressed to say whether the currents cause the wave or the wave causes the currents. Suffice it to say that they are both required for the wave to travel. If a section of the guide is replaced with an insulator, that will kill the traveling wave.

Comment: @user207787 updated my answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it has to do with the Maxwell equations and energy transport. The two important equations for this are:
$$\text{curl}\,\vec{E} = -\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t} \qquad \text{and}\qquad \text{curl}\,\vec{H}=\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\vec{D}}{\partial t}$$

This means that an electric field creates a magnetic one and vice versa. If a harmonic current density \$\vec{J}\$ is impressed, a harmonically changing magnetic field is created. This magnetic field in turn creates a harmonic electric field, which then generates a magnetic field itself. And now you're back to the beginning. Magnetic field -> electric field -> magnetic field -> ... and so on. The way in which the fields are directed towards each other creates a wave that propagates away from the cause (current density).

[This image](https://www.jobilize.com/physics2/test/the-mechanism-of-electromagnetic-wave-propagation-by-openstax) shows the wave propagation (but keep in mind that only one specific direction is shown):
[image: creation of electromagnetic wave]

This does not matter that much at low frequencies, because the derivatives quickly become very small. Derivation means multiplication by \$\text{j}\omega\$, which is why it works better at higher frequencies. But what are high frequencies? What is really important is the dimension in relation to the wavelength. Energy providers, for example, have to take into account certain transmission line effects even at 60 Hz, because distances of several hundred kilometers are covered here in some cases.

But back to the piece of wire (which behaves as an antenna). If you want to direct the electromagnetic wave and thus the energy in one specific direction, special structures are necessary. These structures are transmission lines and waveguides. Waveguides are so named because they guide an (original free space) wave along one direction.